# Auto-scaling databases and connection pool

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, connection-pooling, scaling

At a certain threshold, our database on AWS spawns an additional read replica. Rails doesn't know about this additional replica until it reconnects to the database, but obviously its not going to do that unless it has to, meaning almost all connections stay on the original read replica.

So what do people do in this situation? Is there a way to periodically force activerecord connection pool to terminate all connections and make a new one?

Thanks!